# Php curl запрос через прокси с авторизацией

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Помогите, кто знает, вот функция:

```
function curl_exec_follow($url) {

    $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1';

    // Some websites check referrer
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $scheme = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    $referrer = $scheme . '://' . $host;

    $ch = curl_init();

    $curl_defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_defaults);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,"xxx:xxx");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,"xxx:xxx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    if ( !file_exists('cookie.txt') || !is_writable('cookie.txt') ) {
        echo 'Cookie file is missing or not writable.';
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 10);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $code != '200' ) echo 'http error code: ' . $code . ' error:' . .curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Когда вызываю ее без прокси, всё работает. Когда пробовал работать с бесплатными прокси без авторизации - редко, но иногда работало. Решил, что проблема в том, что они бесплатные и купил платный прокси с авторизацией. При вызове функции `curl_error($ch)` возвращает ошибку `Failed to connect to xxxx port xxxx: Connection refused`

Кто знает, помогите пожалуйста) у меня уже закончились варианты(

Comment: А какой у прокси тип ? Имеется в виду у покупного.

Comment: Тип прокси http/https

Answer (score 1):

Так парни я разобрался. В коде все правильно. Оказывается хостинг провайдеры, как правило запрещают запросы с нестандартными портами. А у прокси серверов они как раз нестандартные. Попросил их разрешить мне отправлять запросы по моему порту и все заработало)